# Ошибка обработки ползовательского пространства имен

Tags: c++, namespace

Обьявил пространство имен `s` для класса `String` и прописал `using namespace s`, но выскакивает ошибка:

> undefined reference to s::operator<<(std::ostream&, s::String const&)

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
namespace s
{
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
class String
{
private: 
     char str[1000];
 friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const String &);
public:
 String();
 String(const char *);
     int size() const;
 short SetStr(const String &);
     String &operator+(const String &);
 bool operator!() const;
 String &operator=(const String &);
     bool operator<(const String &)  const;
 bool operator>(const String &)  const;
 bool operator!=(const String &) const;
 bool operator==(const String &) const;
 const  char operator[](int i) const;
 ~String();

 };

}
String.cpp:    
#include"String.h"
s::String()
{
 str = new char [1000];
 lenght =1000;
}
s::String(const char *s1) 
{
 str= new char [strlen(s1)+1];
 lenght=strlen(str);
 strcpy(str,s1);
 }
String & s::operator=(const String &s1)
{
  char *tempStr=str;
  SetStr(s1);
  delete [] tempStr;
}
int s::size() const
{
  return lenght;
String & s::operator+(const String &s1)
{
    char *tempPtr = str;
    lenght+=s1.size();
    str=new char [lenght+1];
    assert(str!=0);//exit if we dont give the memory
    strcpy(str,tempPtr);
    strcpy(str,s1.str); 
    delete []tempPtr;
}
bool s::operator==(const String &s1) const
{
  return strcmp(s1.str,str)?true:false;
}
bool s::operator!() const
{
   return lenght == 0?:true:false;
 }
bool s::operator>(const String &s1) const
{
   return (lenght > s1.lenght()?true:false;
}
bool s::operator<(const String &s1) const
{
   return lenght < s1.lenght?true:false;
}
const  char s::operator[](int i) const
{ 
  assert(i>=0 && i < lenght);//exit if index under diapazon || >lenght
  return str[i];
}
short s::SetStr(const String &s1)    
{
    str=new char [lenght +1];
    assert(str!=0);
    strcpy(str,s1);
}
ostream &s::operator<<(ostream &out,const String &s)
{
  out<<s.str;
  return out;
     }
 s::~String()
{
 delete[] str;
 lenght=0;
}
main.cpp:
#include"String.h"
using namespace s;
int main()
{
  String s("Hello World!");
    cout<<s<<endl;
    cin.get();
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить #include <ostream>

Comment: Выкинул не весь код.Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @Max: Так где реальный код-то? То, что приведено выше - фейк, который не имеет никаких шансов даже начать компилироваться, не говоря уже о том, чтобы добраться до ошибки *линковки* вроде "undefined reference". Одни `s::String()` и `str = new char [1000]` чего стоят...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли определить оператор

```
std::ostream & s::operator<<(std::ostream &out,const s::String &)
{
    //...
```

Или

```
namespace s
{
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out,const String &)
    {
        //...
```

По крайней мере в тех фрагментах кода, которые вы привели, определение оператора отсутствует.

EDIT: После того, как вы обновили свой код, то в заголовке замените директиву

```
#include<string.h>
```

на

```
#include <cstring>
```

А в модуле напишите определение оператора как

```
std::ostream &s::operator <<( std::ostream &out, const s::String &s )
{
    return out << s.str;
}
```

Но в любом случае ваш код некорректный. Вы объявили член данных класса `str`

```
 char str[1000];
```

как массив, а в конструкторе пишите

```
s::String()
{
 str = new char [1000];
 lenght =1000;
}
```

Во-первых компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошиьке в этом предложении

```
 str = new char [1000];
```

а во-вторых, это просто не имеет смысла.

Comment: Vlad,спасибо за указанные недочеты,но увы это не решило проблему.Проблема в том,что main() не распознает функции-члены класса String:" undefined reference to `s::String::String(char const*)".

Comment: @Max  Как я уже написал, ваша программа некоректная, и компилятор в любом случае не должен ее компилировать. Что касается этой частной проблемы, то, похоже, вы не включили объектный код модуля String.cpp в проект.

Comment: @Max: Не надо придумывать. Никакой ошибки "undefined reference" приведенный вами код выдавать в принципе не может. Если у вас есть реальный код, котрый вы пытаетесь компилировать - давайте его сюда. А то, что вы пока сюда запостили - фейк, никакой осмысленной связи с приведенной вами ошибкой не имеющий.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow:Все так как вы сказали.Первая проблема была в том,что напартачил с конструктором,а вторая,что не подключил String.cpp.Спасибо!